# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know it is a bit silly question yet I am asking this..

I am watching the tutorial of cryptoverse react app from youtube channel JavaScript Mastery.

Mostoff Application is ready and everything works except cryptoDetails.jsx.

As soon as I click on the any crypto currency card, it shows the error in the heading stated above in the console. I am attaching my code and that screenshot so you can help me.Thanks for the help in advance.

CryptoDetails.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import HTMLReactParser from 'html-react-parser';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import millify from 'millify';
import { Col, Row, Typography, Select } from 'antd';
import { MoneyCollectOutlined, DollarCircleOutlined, FundOutlined, ExclamationCircleOutlined, 
StopOutlined, TrophyOutlined, CheckOutlined, NumberOutlined, ThunderboltOutlined } from '@ant- design/icons';

import { useGetCryptoDetailsQuery, useGetCryptoHistoryQuery } from '../services/cryptoApi';
import Loader from './Loader';
import LineChart from './LineChart';

const { Title, Text } = Typography;
const { Option } = Select;

const CryptoDetails = () => {
   const { coinId } = useParams();
   const [timeperiod, setTimeperiod] = useState('7d');
   const { data, isFetching } = useGetCryptoDetailsQuery(coinId);
   const { data: coinHistory } = useGetCryptoHistoryQuery({ coinId, timeperiod });
   const cryptoDetails = data?.data?.coin;

   if (isFetching) return <Loader />;

  const time = ['3h', '24h', '7d', '30d', '1y', '3m', '3y', '5y'];

  const stats = [
   { title: 'Price to USD', value: `$ ${cryptoDetails?.["price"] && millify(cryptoDetails?. 
 ["price"])}`, icon: <DollarCircleOutlined /> },
   { title: 'Rank', value: cryptoDetails?.rank, icon: <NumberOutlined /> },
   { title: '24h Volume', value: `$  ${cryptoDetails?.["24hVolume"] && millify(cryptoDetails?. 
  ["24hVolume"])}`, icon: <ThunderboltOutlined /> },
    { title: 'Market Cap', value: `$ ${cryptoDetails?.["marketCap"] && millify(cryptoDetails?. 
     ["marketCap"])}`, icon: <DollarCircleOutlined /> },
   { title: 'All-time-high(daily avg.)', value: `$ 
    ${millify(cryptoDetails?.allTimeHigh?.price)}`, icon: <TrophyOutlined /> },
```

];

```
const genericStats = [
  { title: 'Number Of Markets', value: cryptoDetails?.numberOfMarkets, icon: <FundOutlined /> 
   },
   { title: 'Number Of Exchanges', value: cryptoDetails?.numberOfExchanges, icon: 
 <MoneyCollectOutlined /> },
   { title: 'Aprroved Supply', value: cryptoDetails?.approvedSupply ? <CheckOutlined /> : 
  <StopOutlined />, icon: <ExclamationCircleOutlined /> },
   { title: 'Total Supply', value: `$ ${millify(cryptoDetails?.totalSupply)}`, icon: 
 <ExclamationCircleOutlined /> },
  { title: 'Circulating Supply', value: `$ ${millify(cryptoDetails?.circulatingSupply)}`, 
   icon: <ExclamationCircleOutlined /> },
 ];

return (
     <Col className="coin-detail-container">
     <Col className="coin-heading-container">
      <Title level={2} className="coin-name">
        {data?.data?.coin.name} ({data?.data?.coin.slug}) Price
      </Title>
      <p>{cryptoDetails.name} live price in US Dollar (USD). View value statistics, market cap 
   and supply.</p>
  </Col>
  <Select defaultValue="7d" className="select-timeperiod" placeholder="Select Timeperiod" onChange={(value) => setTimeperiod(value)}>
    {time.map((date) => <Option key={date}>{date}</Option>)}
  </Select>
  <LineChart coinHistory={coinHistory} currentPrice={millify(cryptoDetails.price)} coinName={cryptoDetails.name} />
  <Col className="stats-container">
    <Col className="coin-value-statistics">
      <Col className="coin-value-statistics-heading">
        <Title level={3} className="coin-details-heading">{cryptoDetails?.name} Value Statistics</Title>
        <p>An overview showing the statistics of {cryptoDetails?.name}, such as the base and quote currency, the rank, and trading volume.</p>
      </Col>
      {stats.map(({ icon, title, value }) => (
        <Col className="coin-stats">
          <Col className="coin-stats-name">
            <Text>{icon}</Text>
            <Text>{title}</Text>
          </Col>
          <Text className="stats">{value}</Text>
        </Col>
      ))}
    </Col>
    <Col className="other-stats-info">
      <Col className="coin-value-statistics-heading">
        <Title level={3} className="coin-details-heading">Other Stats Info</Title>
        <p>An overview showing the statistics of {cryptoDetails?.name}, such as the base and quote currency, the rank, and trading volume.</p>
      </Col>
      {genericStats.map(({ icon, title, value }) => (
        <Col className="coin-stats">
          <Col className="coin-stats-name">
            <Text>{icon}</Text>
            <Text>{title}</Text>
          </Col>
          <Text className="stats">{value}</Text>
        </Col>
      ))}
    </Col>
  </Col>
  <Col className="coin-desc-link">
    <Row className="coin-desc">
      <Title level={3} className="coin-details-heading">What is {cryptoDetails?.name}?</Title>
      {HTMLReactParser(cryptoDetails.description)}
    </Row>
    <Col className="coin-links">
      <Title level={3} className="coin-details-heading">{cryptoDetails?.name} Links</Title>
      {cryptoDetails?.links?.map((link) => (
        <Row className="coin-link" key={link.name}>
          <Title level={5} className="link-name">{link.type}</Title>
          <a href={link.url} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">{link.name}</a>
        </Row>
      ))}
    </Col>
  </Col>
</Col>
);
};

export default CryptoDetails;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72UTS.png)

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. Also: _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_ (from: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: can you provide the cryptodetails json as well, which is from data.data.coin. Because it looks like the the value is not set.

Comment: is your cryptoApi correct?
i guess the problem with fetching data

Comment: Thanks guys found the error and debugged it and sorry it was my first time asking the question so pardon any wrong methods. I am trying to be better

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).